SSH with vscode into Raspberry Pi not working
I want to SSH into my Raspberry Pi with VSCode, but I am not succeeding. SSH is installed and working via CMD, but not working with VSCode SSH. When I try to make a connection, it says to select a host platform, but Raspbian or Raspberry Pi OS is not available. Selecting Linux does not work either. I have not seen anyone else experience this when trying to connect to Raspberry Pi.
I have already verified that SSH is working, the SSH extension is installed. It says connection could not be established.

This usually works really reliably. Are you specifying a valid username in the IP address when setting up the connection? You should type something like 'pi@192.168.1.123', not '192.168.1.123'. (And then select 'Linux')
